# Does "surfeit" have an adjectival counterpart?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I’m thinking of something like *surfeitous*, but obviously that’s not a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try **overabundant** or **overindulgent**, depending on how you mean surfeit.

Comment: Both of these (current) answers are pretty good. I'm going with yours as I think it fits the connotation a bit better, but both are solid answers.

Answer (score 2):

Excessive, intemperate, superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The OED attests (what it calls) the participial adjective ***surfeited***, meaning:

> Fed or filled to excess; oppressed or disordered by or as by over-feeding.

The first citation is from Shakespeare, and two of the later ones are:

> - 1842 Manning *Serm*. (1848) I. 22 — Take a watchful, self-denying man..and compare him with the heavy, surfeited man.
> - 1886 H. F. Lester *Under Two Fig Trees* 182 — And then divide the morsel among these already surfeited gluttons.

The now rare word ***surfeiting*** is not an adjective, but a verbal noun (or “gerund”) with the same sense as *surfeit* itself.  For example:

> - 1821 Lamb *Elia* Ser. i. *Grace before Meat*, — Gluttony and surfeiting are no proper occasions of thanksgiving.

Answer (score 0):

#### Surplus

This adjective can be applied to a thing that is present in excess of technical need, with the remainder being available for use elsewhere. I use this when there was an option of keeping this surplus, i.e. it isn't harmful.

```
Surplus food was distributed to the poor.

This year's finances have resulted in a rare budget surplus.
```

#### Excess

This is particularly useful when the extra amount is harmful, and it is necessary to remove it.

```
Remove the excess water with paper towels.

Cut away the excess pastry, leaving neat edges.
```

#### Excessive, Overabundant

These are useful when the thing that is in surfeit can't have a part removed from it (and discarded or given away). For example, this applies when it is a property of a person.

```
The soldier couldn't fit in the tank because of his excessive height.

His overabundant enthusiasm was a little annoying to the others.
```